# how can I take a time reversal of an array and conv it in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, convolution

I have an h[n] = [1 1 1 -1 1] for [0:4] and I have h[-n] = [1 -1 1 1 1] for [-4:0]. so the question is since matlab index starts from 1, how do I make my array starts from 0, and how do I make the h[-n] to start from -4 so I can do convolution? please help, I am new to matlab!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you don't.

The long answer is that MATLAB has a very unique and specific manner of indexing and counting. The idea behind it is supposedly for faster and easier matrix manipulation by the user.

Given:
H = [1 1 1 -1 -1]
for all indices in order all you need to do is call
H[:]

If you want to flip the vector you should use the built in flip() command:
flip(H)

If you're attempting to iterate through a loop, then you want to use some sort of counting like:
for i=5:-1:1
     ...code...

I'd suggest reading up on array indexing as well as counting methods for loops to get a stronger understanding on the subject. These are some key points of MATLAB that you'll want to learn early if you plan on using it more in the future.

Comment: that's what I had in mind at first but, if I am doing the convolution of the two, then I am going to get a different plot than the theoretical one, because both are going to start from 1